# Get Group By Column in result set without using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the following query

```
select CAST(DepositeDate AS DATE) as DepositeDate,SUM(TotalAmount) as Amount
from Payment
group by DepositeDate
```

I am getting the following result.

```
DepositeDate | Amount | 
2021-04-30   | 50     | 
2021-04-30   | 50     | 
2021-04-26   | 75     | 
2021-04-11   | 30     | 
2021-04-11   | 30     |
```

But I need the following result

```
DepositeDate | Amount | 
2021-04-30   | 100    | 
2021-04-26   | 75     | 
2021-04-11   | 60     |
```

Is this possible without using CTE?

Comment: Does this return correct result? `select CAST(DepositeDate AS DATE) as DepositeDate,SUM(TotalAmount) as Amount from Payment group by CAST(DepositeDate AS DATE)`

Comment: And whats the reason for not using a CTE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, your `DepositeDate` column has a time component.  Repeat the expression in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select CAST(DepositeDate AS DATE) as DepositeDate,
       SUM(TotalAmount) as Amount
from Payment
group by CAST(DepositeDate AS DATE) 
order by CAST(DepositeDate AS DATE);
```

SQL Server does not recognize aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  So `DepositeDate` is always going to refer to a column defined in the `FROM` clause and not the expression in the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

**A slightly cleaner version of Gordon's answer, which enforces the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), is to place the conversion into an `APPLY`**

This means you only define the conversion to `date` once, and can use it in all other parts of the query

```sql
select v.DepositeDate,
       SUM(p.TotalAmount) as Amount
from Payment p
cross apply (values (CAST(p.DepositeDate AS DATE) ) ) v(DepositeDate)
group by v.DepositeDate
order by v.DepositeDate;
```