# CASE WHEN and GROUP BY just truncates the results?

Tags: sql-server

So, what happens here is that when the results are displayed, it doesn't combine the column name, but just truncates it. It still shows multiple rows.

```
select distinct 
    
    CASE WHEN ARPDisplayName0  like 'Crystal Reports 2008%' THEN 'Crystal Reports 2008'
    WHEN ARPDisplayName0  like 'Crystal Reports 2011%'   THEN 'Crystal Reports 2011'
    ELSE ARPDisplayName0  END ARPDisplayName0,
    count(ARPDisplayName0) as Software_Count

from v_gs_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE

where
ARPDisplayName0  like '%Crystal Reports%'

group by ARPdisplayname0
order by ARPDisplayName0
```

The results should be one entry:
"Crystal Reports 2008"

not multiple:
"Crystal Reports 2008"
"Crystal Reports 2008"
"Crystal Reports 2008"
"Crystal Reports 2008"
"Crystal Reports 2008"

**UPDATE:**
So, the fix was a subquery

```
select ARPDisplayName0, count(*) as Total
from
(
select 
    
    CASE WHEN ARPDisplayName0  like 'Crystal Reports 2008%' THEN 'Crystal Reports 2008'
    WHEN ARPDisplayName0  like 'Crystal Reports 2011%'   THEN 'Crystal Reports 2011'
    ELSE ARPDisplayName0  END ARPDisplayName0,
    count(ARPDisplayName0) as Software_Count

from v_gs_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE

where
ARPDisplayName0  like '%Crystal Reports%'

)t

group by ARPDisplayName0
order by ARPDisplayName0
```

Comment: Can you give here what you get and what you expect as to more clarification?

Comment: Sure. I added it above

Comment: Try aliasing your case statement as something other than an existing column name and see what that yields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Group By Column in result set without using CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366478/get-group-by-column-in-result-set-without-using-cte) You can put into a `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` this allows you to refer to it anywhere in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I have to learn something every day. The fix was a subquery (not my tea)

```
select ARPDisplayName0, count(*) as Total
from
(
select 
    
    CASE WHEN ARPDisplayName0  like 'Crystal Reports 2008%' THEN 'Crystal Reports 2008'
    WHEN ARPDisplayName0  like 'Crystal Reports 2011%'   THEN 'Crystal Reports 2011'
    ELSE ARPDisplayName0  END ARPDisplayName0,
    count(ARPDisplayName0) as Software_Count

from v_gs_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE

where
ARPDisplayName0  like '%Crystal Reports%'

)t

group by ARPDisplayName0
order by ARPDisplayName0
```

Comment: Yes, nice work. The reason is that your CASE statement is applied to the output of the results set returned by the GROUP BY. When you do your string replacement in the subquery and then apply the GROUP BY to the subquery output, you get the result desired.

Comment: May be need to add `group by ARPDisplayName0` in subquery as well otherwise it suppose to throw error ;)

Comment: This is going to give you interesting results: firstly, you can't have `count` without a `group by` in the inner query, and if you add it then the outer count will just count the number of groups. You need to define `ARPDisplayName0` without any aggregates first, then group by that value and count. Also `count(ARPDisplayName0)` is the same as `count(*)` or `count(1)` if `ARPDisplayName0` is not nullable

Comment: The problem is all in the group by - since you group by the column instead of group by the expression.  You can copy the case expression to the group by and that would fix the issue.  And...no need for DISTINCT with a GROUP BY - it is redundant.